# How to determine which type to dynamic_cast to?

Tags: c++, dynamic-cast

I've been reading tutorials on `dynamic_cast` for a program I'm working on, and I'm not quite grasping how to utilize it.

I have multiple methods which will pass in parameters that are superclass pointers, and from there, differentiate between which is which to figure out what operations to make.

For example, the superclass might be `Value`, and the subclass is `RationalNumber`.

My plan was to set an `int` value ID for `RationalNumber` to be, I don't know, 1, and then when I use `dynamic_cast`, it will determine that the `Value*` object is actually a `RationalNumber`, and the operation will be performed.

How am I able to implement this?

Comment: Why are you trying to "implement" `dynamic_cast`?  It's built into the language!  Are you merely trying to determine whether a `dynamic_cast` will succeed or fail?  Are you even certain it's necessary?  When you have virtual interfaces, it's usually not necessary.

Comment: I mean, how would I go about utilizing it? I'm passing superclass pointers into methods and I need to determine what type of subclass the pointer is referring to. I'm pretty sure it's necessary for what I'm trying to do. Multiple subclasses are going to be derived from one superclass, and the operation performed is going to be different based on which one is stored in the pointer. It's only to prevent having to create a method for every possible combination of parameter.

Comment: Again, if absolutely possible, use a virtual function in the interface for your task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typical example:

```
class Value
{
 public:
   virtual ~Value();
};

class RationalNumber : public Value
{
  ... 
}


Value *v = new RationalNumber(...)


... 
RationalNumber* test = dynamic_cast<RationalNumber*>(v);

if (v)
   cout << "v is a rational number" << endl;
else
   cout << "v is a not rational number" << endl;
```

Note however that this is NOT a good solution in nearly all cases where you have inheritance. I'm writing a compiler, and it's the first time I've ever used `dynamic_cast` - mostly because there are some fairly generic functions that deal with (for example) `ExprAST` class pointers, and to add ALL of the variants of functions that all the derived classes (31 classes at present count) of has into the `ExprAST` would be rather unpractical. (And of course, having a call that does `expr->isVariableExprAST()` is not that much better than `VariableExprAST* var = dynamic_cast<VariableExprAST*>(expr); if (var) ...` - it's the same amount of code, more or less).

But in most cases, NOT knowing what type you deal with is a much better solution.

A more suitable solution is to use a virtual function that is common for all classes, e.g:

```
class Value
{
 public:
   virtual ~Value();
   virtual void SomeMethod() = 0;
};

class RationalNumber : public Value
{
  ... 
  virtual void SomeMethod() { ... }
}

class IrrationalNumber : public Value
{
  ... 
  virtual void SomeMethod() { ... }
}


Value *v = ... 

v->SomeMethod();
```

In this case, you will not need to do ANY checks - you just need to implement the method `SomeMethod` for all subtypes.

Comment: In this program, the operation to be performed is dependent on the object stored by the value pointer. So if *v is pointing to a RationalNumber as opposed to an IrrationalNumber, something else will happen. Can I get around this by creating the ID value and keeping a virtual method to check the ID, and depending on the value of the ID, perform each?

For example, in this case, RationalNumber's ID = 1.

`RationalNumber::checkID{
   return ID;
}

if (v->checkID == 1 && w->checkID == 1){
    //execute method
}
else if ...` ?

Comment: That seems like a BAD solution, and I have edited my answer to explain how you, normally solve this problem, when you haven't got 30-odd classes that have quite different set of functionality (for example a variable has an address, but there is no address of a for-loop or a binary expression.

Answer (score 2):

The `dynamic_cast` operator determines the type of an object during runtime, according to the value of the object's V-Table pointer (an implicit member field that is added to the class of the object when you have one or more virtual functions in that class).

There is nothing to implement here, and you can simply call it. For example:

```
bool isRationalNumber(Value* object)
{
    RationalNumber* number = dynamic_cast<RationalNumber*>(object);
    if (number == NULL)
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

Please note that you cannot use it on a class which does not declare **at least** one virtual function, as such class does not have a V-Table.

In addition, on some compilers you need to enable RTTI in the project settings.

And finally - a small suggestion (more of a personal opinion, so you may choose to ignore it):

Dynamic cast is pretty much in contrast with the concept of Polymorphism, in which you generalize objects with common attributes under a single base-class, and then refer to them using that **generic** base-class. With dynamic cast, you are essentially doing the opposite, as you are checking the **specific** type of the object before deciding what action to take.

So the suggestion is, try to avoid using it whenever possible.

If you see you have no alternatives, then check your design.

Comment: I'm not trying to implement the methods in the classes. There are separate classes which have methods that pass in Value pointers and operate depending on what object the Value pointers store. I get that it's kind of counter-intuitive, but I was talking with a few other people on this and they planted the seed and at this point, it seems to be the best way to accomplish what it needs to.

Comment: @user3502205: There might be cases where `dynamic_cast` is the best (or only) alternative. As I said, it is more of a personal opinion that you should try to avoid using it (and check your design if you see you have no alternatives). Some people will claim against this opinion, so you may choose to ignore it. Using the operator itself is pretty simple, as shown in the answer above.

Answer (score 1):

The standard way is to `dynamic_cast` the object to the derived class and then test if the result is `null` or not. For example (using your terminology):

```
void method(SuperClass* object) {

  SubClass* subclass = dynamic_cast<SubClass*>(object);

  if (subclass) {
    // the object is a 'SubClass'
    // do stuff...
  }

}
```

If you have several subclasses, you'll have to check them separately. E.g.:

```
void method(SuperClass* object) {

  SubClass_1* subclass_1 = dynamic_cast<SubClass_1*>(object);
  if (subclass_1) {
    // the object is a 'SubClass_1'
    // do stuff...
    return;
  }

  SubClass_2* subclass_2 = dynamic_cast<SubClass_2*>(object);
  if (subclass_2) {
    // the object is a 'SubClass_2'
    // do stuff...
    return;
  }


}
```